# Change file name in linux is is change in mtime or ctime

Tags: linux, mtime

I  created a file called as test.war. If I change it to test.war.backup by copying and renaming via cp command, is this change in mtime or ctime? What about for rename mv command, is it ctime or mtime

Comment: If you actually mean to copy a file rather than to rename a file, maybe rephrase the question to make it less confusing? (If you want to rename, you would use `mv`)

Comment: Got 2 1 will be copy (cp) and another will be rename (mv)